# Run pm2 on Azure Devops Deployment Group

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, pm2

I am using Azure Devops for CI/CD.

I have on prem Windows servers that are in a Deployment Group.

I have a pipeline that will run based on a github trigger.

It provides Continuous Deployment for Node.js sites on the Windows Servers.

I use pm2 to run the Node sites.

Everything works in the release pipeline up until I need to restart pm2.

How do I run a pm2 restart command on the Windows Servers in the Deployment Group?

Answer (score 0):

I used npm running a script via the package.json.

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod && pm2 restart server.js",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Comment: How did you run PM2 with deployment group? I am having an issue when the build and launch of PM2 processes is successful, but after the build finishes, all processes die.
I am using a Powershell script to manually run the scripts: "prod": "pm2 start pm2.yml". Do you know what can be an issue?